# Is there anyway to use the Android Facebook SDK 2.0 Login experience with the 3.0 sdk?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, user-interface, facebook-android-sdk

Sorry for the simplicity of the question, but the 3.0 Login experience is very different from the 2.0 experience. The 2.0 experience provides a richer (yet slower) multi-activity login process where as the 3.0 experience is mostly one Activity with at least one popup. Facebook authentication is very important for our app, as it is for most everyone that provides this type of integration and we would like the best user experience for our users. Most people are used to the previous version and our product manager is fairly worried about our login rate. My team and I have finished the 3.0 Login and some posting functionality and we would really prefer to not go back to the 2.0 sdk.

I have looked at the various tutorials and examples on the developers.facebook.com site including the Session API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session and I don't see anything that would let us do this. Short of reverse engineering the 2.0 sdk to see if I can pull out the appropriate code (which probably wouldn't work anyway for many reasons). Obviously, going back to an older sdk that is mostly deprecated simply for a different user experience is a bad solution plus Facebook will be removing support for 2.0 on June 13th of this year (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/13/facebook-sdk-3-0-for-android-and-native-login/).

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Jared

Comment: What part of the 3.0 experience are you concerned with? As more and more apps adopt the 3.0 SDK, users will become used to the 3.0 UX, and using a different flow will actually be a detriment to conversion. Currently we do not provide a method for using the 2.0 method for auth in 3.0, if you feel strongly about the product decisions that were made in 3.0, I encourage you to join the Facebook Developers group (https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) and start a conversation there.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will join up. The experience that we are concerned with is the login where it is not an immersive Facebook provided, multi-activity/fragment experience which users are more accustomed to. The 3.0 experience is a quicker single or dual dialog at least on the Android side. As Facebook login is critical to some features of our application we are worried that a lot of users will be turned off by the new UI and not think its really a Facebook style login.